# OAUTH - Azure Identity Management - Reply to URL. JWT token is removed when going to AWS

Tags: java, azure, amazon-web-services, oauth

### Set-up

I'm attempting to use OAUTH Azure Identity Management.  The Reply-To url is Tomcat Java application hosted in AWS.

### The low-down

Azure will attempt to send the token to the Reply-To url like this:
http://my-aws-url/#id_token=eyJ0eXAi...  --> Notice the '#' and not a '?'.
The MSFT tech said 'that's the expected behavior and its not configurable.'

### The Issue

When the Request hits my AWS Service, the JWT Token is missing.  Everything including the '#' is missing.  I understand Servers take this to be a page fragment and will remove it. I know that page fragments will not survive redirects.

### Solution ??

Does the Reply-To url Service need to be hosted on Azure also?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
What happens is correct.  Because of the '#' in the url, you need to have a front-end app that can take the url and THEN re-send it to your application with the JWT token in the header or body.  Stupid, stupid, stupid.

- I have a basic front-end that has jquery getting the url, modify the url (so my Application's backend can receive the token( place the JWT token in the header), and make a request to the back-end.